# Change background color on SU signature blocks

Tags: feature-request

On SuperUser the signature block background color seems too similar to the color of the name. Can the color be made to have a bit more contrast to the text?

It seems to only be an issue on the question as the answers have a white background and are not a problem. I am making this request because it is difficult for me to see, not for reasons of personal taste in color coordination.

Comment: Looks good to me... Would you prefer *Blue on Black*? (http://vimeo.com/5250904)

Comment: If I remember correctly Jonathan has whipped up some greasemonkey scripts to change themes in the past... I'm sure it wouldn't be hard to fix this with a small greasemonkey script.

Comment: For one, greasemonkey is unfamiliar to me. Two, if I wanted *Blue on Black*, I'd go buy it. Three, what's wrong with simply giving me a tip on changing it rather than a down-vote. I have difficulty seeing the difference in the color - not simply a suggestion based on my personal taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, might I suggest the [Stylish Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) which allows you to provide user-styles that will be applied wherever you like.

If you approach this issue from an accessibility vantage you have a stronger request. But even then, it may be faster/easier to install the aforementioned plugin and setup your own color-schemes to make aspects of the site (or web in general) more accessible to those who have difficulties distinguishing between foreground and background.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I agree that the contrast is low in that area.  Jeff was already burned out by the whole red/green upvote/downvote tally, though, and I get the strong impression that the designers never consulted a color accessibility website when choosing the palette(s).

So, don't hold your breath...

Comment: I learned a long time ago, only hold your breath under water. But, the Stylish Addon may do what I want.